# Storing objects in session within MultiActionController page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to store/cache a List within a Controller in Spring 3.0

Thanks
Gauls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many parameter types are supported in your controller, including `HttpServletRequest`.  Once you have the request, you can call `request.getSession();` to retrieve the session.
Check out section "15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types" in the Spring 3.0 reference for a complete list.

Spring documentation (including the reference doc) is available here: http://www.springsource.org/documentation

Comment: Thanks for replying yes i am using session= request.getSession();

Comment: Is this the best way to do this in spring?